# SharePoint API: Create a page with custom HTML on a communications site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I need to create a new page on a SharePoint Communications Site programmatically, using the SharePoint APIs. The URL of this site looks like this: https://[sharepoint url]/sites/KnowledgeBase

And this is basically what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I am able to make authenticated requests to SharePoint using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom). I have that working in Postman. Unfortunately, I can't find any reliable documentation or a tutorial on how to create a new (modern) page with custom HTML content, using the REST API.

I was able to find [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-create?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) on creating a page with the Graph API. However, I'm not sure if the Graph API is the right option, since it is still in beta, and the integration I'm building will go into Production.

Any help or insight on how to do this, and which API to use, would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the technology/platform are you using for your application (if any)? I mean, like .net or javascript, or something else? There are libraries that wrap REST API simplifying the task. Or maybe you are talking about scripting, like powershell or python?

Comment: I can use either .NET or Javascript. But I'd prefer Javascript, since the accompanying code is written in Node.js. I'm basically integrating Salesforce with SharePoint, and the Salesforce side is already done in Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Microsoft pnpjs library to simplify your life (it wraps the REST API), it has built-in support for client-side pages:

```js
const sp = spfi(...);

// simplest add a page example
const page = await sp.web.addClientsidePage("mypage1");
```

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/webs/#client-side-pages

Comment: Hey thanks! I think the pnpjs library will work for my use case. I was also able to use the [pnp-auth](https://github.com/SharePoint-NodeJS/pnp-auth) package to use my existing authentication strategy.